# Javascript repetition of events

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the focus is on the input was only one time it works but if more then attached event begins to work as many times as eliment was in focus. How to make a click event to execute only once? Below is the code.

```
$('.menuName').focusin(function(){  

        $(this).parent().append('<div class="cleartext" style="position: absolute;right: 0px;top: 0px;height: 38px;width:32px;z-index: 999;"><i class="icon-remove-circle"></i></div>');

        inputclr = $(this);
        intutval = $(inputclr).val();

        $(document).on('click', '.cleartext', function() {

            $('.menuName').placeholder();
                $(inputclr).attr('placeholder',intutval);
            $('.pinch_text').html('click');
            $(inputclr).val('').focus();

        });
    });
```

Comment: Move the `click` handler **outside** of the `focusin` handler, so they each are bound **once**. Then update the variables inside the `click` handler

Comment: *"Why does my event trigger once for each time i focus the element?"* because you are binding the event every time you focus the element...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove any listeners by using the off function:

```
$(document).off('click','.cleartext').on('click', '.cleartext', function() {

    $('.menuName').placeholder();
        $(inputclr).attr('placeholder',intutval);
    $('.pinch_text').html('click');
    $(inputclr).val('').focus();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Bring your code outside focus event

```
 $(document).on('click', '.cleartext', function() {

            $('.menuName').placeholder();
                $(inputclr).attr('placeholder',intutval);
            $('.pinch_text').html('click');
            $(inputclr).val('').focus();

        });
var inputclr , intutval ;
$('.menuName').focusin(function(){  

        $(this).parent().append('<div class="cleartext" style="position: absolute;right: 0px;top: 0px;height: 38px;width:32px;z-index: 999;"><i class="icon-remove-circle"></i></div>');

        inputclr = $(this);
        intutval = $(inputclr).val();


    });
```